# How to modify the car controllers to do it more Arcade and less realistic in Unity 5 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the Unity 5 Car Asset coming with the Standard Assets. Controls are very hard. The car flips easily even if you are going at quite slow speed.

I have done some "tricks" I have found on the Internet like [increasing the mass of the rigid body to 1500](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/268931/car-movement-basics.html), adding the [Stabilizer bars (A.K.A. anti-roll bars) script to the car](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/21417/my-car-keeps-fliping-over-i-have-an-idea-how-to-fi.html), and setting the [gravity center of the car in a fake perfect center](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/634376/car-flips-when-it-turns-1.html). I have included the last versions of those scripts above.

**I don't want to simulate perfect physics. I want a fun car easy to ride. Is it possible with Unity?**

> Script: gravity center of the car in a fake perfect center

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class carflipfix : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().centerOfMass = new Vector3(0, -1, 0);    
    }
}
```

> Script: stabilizer bars (A.K.A. anti-roll bars).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AntiRollBar : MonoBehaviour {
    public WheelCollider wheelL;
    public WheelCollider wheelR;
    public float antiRollVal = 5000f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        WheelHit hit;
        float travelL=1.0f;
        float travelR=1.0f;
        bool groundedL = wheelL.GetGroundHit(out hit);
        if (groundedL){
            travelL = (-wheelL.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point).y - wheelL.radius) / wheelL.suspensionDistance;
        }
        bool groundedR = wheelR.GetGroundHit(out hit);
        if (groundedR){
            travelR = (-wheelR.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point).y - wheelR.radius) / wheelR.suspensionDistance;                   
        }

        float antiRollForce = (travelL - travelR) * antiRollVal;

        if (groundedL)

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForceAtPosition(wheelL.transform.up * -antiRollForce,

                                         wheelL.transform.position);  

        if (groundedR)

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForceAtPosition(wheelR.transform.up * antiRollForce,

                                         wheelR.transform.position);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we remove the [Rigidbody component](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html), we won't be using the Unity physics. Then, we could move the car as we wish getting the input (from the keyboard, gamepad...) to multiply it by the current position of the car. It would be something like:

```
public class Car: MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Update() {  
        // NOTICE THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE IS NOT CORRECT. THE CORRECT WAY SHOULD BE SOMETHING SIMILAR THOUGH:
        gameObject.transform.position += input * Time.deltaTime * gameObject.transform.position; 
    }
}
```